# call a single page from two different link in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, register, link

I added two link on index page.Both are redirecting to same registration page.

[image]

I want,when someone click on "SELLER" then 
"Do You Want To Become Seller / Vendor?" this should not display.

[image]

How can i get where user click on "signup" or "seller".?
and in which file we have to change ?

Comment: Hi Urvashi and welcome to MageOverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: hi Fabian,I just add "seller" link to index page ,I tried to create new page for seller registration having same code as signup page...and add that page from back end after that from front end i click on seller it redirect to new page which is seller.phtml but  it is not showing the all fields.                 so it was not working for me?

Comment: if it is possible to manage this thing on single page(registration.phtml) ? instead of redirect or crate different page .

Answer (score 2):

I would add a url rewrite and then check inside of the template somehow for the path, then show it or not.

Comment: mr.fabian blechschmidt  this problem my localhost   different link in magento.how can remove it

Comment: Sorry, I don'T understand what your problem is. What link is different? And what do you want to remove?